# jQuery UI doesn't apply the theme to a button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-button

I'd like to apply the jQuery UI theme to a button but I couldn't! Why? Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<script src="_code/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="_code/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="_code/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<button>Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is a normal button without jQuery UI theme!
Thanks in advance

Comment: which theme? i can't see any one of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI, unlike, say, jQuery Mobile, does not automatically apply widgets to the elements in your page.

You have to explicitly create a [button](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/) widget around your `<button>` element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").button();
});
```

Comment: In the demo page of jQuery there isn't this function. There is no function at all! And if I add that code to mine nothing happens.

Comment: @Koccy see this example [jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqZcG/) the code of Frédéric Hamidi works fine...

Answer (score 0):

That is because you haven't wrote anything about applying a particular theme to the button. Please learn the basic syntax and usage of jquery: [w3schoos.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp). The files that you linked would usually give them javascript functions which would happen when you write some jquery code. Some jquery code is also needed. If you took it from a website, then please take a complete tutorial.

Comment: I simply looked to the code of jQuery UI demo page and there's no jQuery code inside

Comment: As Frédéric Hamidi said, $("button").button();. This .button(); is the trigger that would cause a function. The actual thing would be mentioned or atleast somewhere in the files

Comment: Please give me the file or link from where you got it

Comment: Now it works. I used the `$("button").button();` method. However I cannot understand how this> http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/button/default.html can work!

Comment: @Koccy, did you miss the call to `button()` on line 14 of that page's source?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have just included the jquery UI files. jquery UI works if you call the functions which are available in jquery UI for different purpose.Eg--

$( "#txtprofession" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });

this is the code for autocomplete functionality.here '#txtprofession' this is the id of textbox on which i want autocomplete functionality to be implement.If i don't call the autocomplete() function which is available in jquery UI until then jquery UI theme would not be implementd on the textbox as some classes are to be passed on that textbox by calling the function.